# openssl crypto memory leak

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl

I have a problem with openssl crypto library, after doing decryption even after exiting function scope, decrypted string is not removed from memory. My code:

```
int crypto::aes_decrypt(const crypto::vector<unsigned char> &data, const crypto::string &key, const crypto::string &iv,
                        crypto::vector<unsigned char> &decrypted) {
    try {
        int len;
        int plaintext_len;
        const auto *dataArr = data.data();
        size_t dataLength = data.size();

        if (key.length() != 32 || iv.length() != 16) {
            return -1;
        }

        auto *plaintext = new unsigned char[dataLength + 16];

        EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
        if (ctx == nullptr) {
            return -2;
        }

        const auto *keyArr = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(key.data());
        const auto *ivArr = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(iv.data());

        /*
         * Initialise the decryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
         * and IV size appropriate for your cipher
         * In this example we are using 256-bit AES (i.e. a 256-bit key). The
         * IV size for *most* modes is the same as the block size. For AES this
         * is 128 bits
         */
        if (1 != EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), nullptr, keyArr, ivArr, 0)) {
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
            return -3;
        }

        /*
        * Provide the message to be decrypted, and obtain the plaintext output.
        * EVP_DecryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary.
        */
        if (1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, dataArr, dataLength)) {
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
            return -4;
        }

        plaintext_len = len;

        /*
         * Finalise the decryption. Further plaintext bytes may be written at
         * this stage.
         */

        if (1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len)) {
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
            return -5;
        }

        plaintext_len += len;
        decrypted = crypto::vector<unsigned char>(plaintext, plaintext + plaintext_len);

        /* Clean up */
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        free(plaintext);
        return 0;

    } catch (exception &e) {
#ifdef DEBUG_SHARED_LIBRARIES
        cout << "Error while aes decrypting: " << e.what() << endl;
#endif
        return -99;
    }
}
```

```
void test() {
    string key = "abcdefghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnop";
    string iv = "1234567890123456";
    string b64 = "82fgiOvXUXrnkGeRsCjKgA==";
    
    vector<unsigned char> decrypted;
    int i = crypto::aes_decrypt(crypto::base64_decode(b64), key, iv, decrypted);
    if (i != 0) {
        cout << "Error: " << i << endl;
        return;
    }

    string dec = {decrypted.begin(), decrypted.end()};

//    cout << "Decrypted raw: " << string_utils::char_array_to_hex(decrypted.data(), decrypted.size()) << endl;
    cout << "Decrypted: " << dec << endl;

    cout << "Click to clear" << endl;
    string input;
    getline(cin, input);
}
```

I tried many combinations, but with string and vector still the same - decrypted string is still in memory

Before exiting function scope:

[image]

After exiting function scope:

[image]

and inside that memory dump:

[image]

and another:

[image]

Any suggestions how can i deal with it? I think its something wrong with aes decrypt implementation, because in memory dump there are many encryption methods related to openssl crypto library

Comment: tried to replace free with delete[] plaintext; but the same result

Comment: That's a good start, actually `new[]` pairs with `delete[]`. Using `free` on an allocation provided by `new[]` has undefined results., so don't use `free`.

Comment: It's inefficient to clear memory and C++ follows a policy of not doing anything that takes up resources unless you explicitly ask for it. If you want that memory cleared, you have to ask for it to be cleared by writing more code or calling a function like `memset`.

Comment: It also takes time and resources to put memory back, so programs generally don't until they have to. Freeing memory only means you promise not to use it again and that it can be safely reused. The system may or may not take it back, and usually won't until it's forced to because someone else needs it. And even then a program may hang on to freed memory so that it can save time if it has to get it again in the future.

Comment: Here's a thought: define your own "secure memory" class that follows RAII, allocating the storage required in the constructor, clearing the storage by writing zeros or random numbers over it before releasing it in the destructor, and adding appropriate guards to the copy and move special member functions.

Comment: Terminology note: In programming a Memory Leak doesn't mean information is leaked by released memory, it means that the memory *was not released* and has been "lost".

Comment: @user4581301 but i should use that instead of string and vector structs? And also maybe that kind of solution already exist?

Comment: You can write over the contents of the `string` and the `vector` before you let them go out of scope with tools like `std::fill`. My point is if something has a cost, clearing a buffer takes time to write in all those zeroes, and the documentation for a data structure or function doesn't explicitly say it performs some optional, resource-consuming task, it almost certainly will not happen.

Comment: I can assure you someone has all the secure memory tools you'll likely ever need written and packaged in a convenient library. Who wrote it and where you can get it... That I don't know. But the folks hanging around at Stack Exchange's Crypto and Infosec sites probably do.

Comment: @user4581301 but as you can see in memory dump, problem exists with crypto:: function, string/vector within test() function are removed from memory

Comment: You need to check the contract outlined in each crypto function's documentation for what they do with the memory they use and used. If they don't specifically state they clear the memory when they are done, they probably do not.

Comment: As for `string` and `vector`, they are not specified to provide data security. Unless you have a Standard Library implementation written specifically for Infosec, you can pretty much count on them not doing anything the Standard doesn't explicitly require and what they do will be implemented to be as fast and efficient as possible.

Comment: @user4581301 *If you want that memory cleared, you have to ask for it to be cleared by writing more code or calling a function like `memset`.*  But a `memset()` of memory that's immediately freed will likely be optimized away.  Even code that clears the memory is likely to be elided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what i was looking for here:

https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption

```
typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, zallocator<char> > secure_string;
```

that `secure_string` is wiped out from memory when leaving the function scope.

Answer (score 3):

To clean memory, OpenSSL provides [the `OPENSSL_cleanse()` function](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man3/OPENSSL_cleanse.html):

> `OPENSSL_cleanse()` fills `ptr` of size `len` with a string of 0's. ...

You can not safely use functions such as `memset()` to clear memory before you deallocate it - compilers are allowed to optimize away such calls since they have no effect on the program per the C and C++ standards.  C does provide [the `memset_s()` function in the optional Annex K](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.7.4.1), and that *will* clear the memory:

> ... Unlike memset, any call to the memset_s function shall be evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine as described in ([5.1.2.3](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3)). That is, any call to the memset_s function shall assume that the memory indicated by s and n may be accessible in the future and thus must contain the values indicated by c.

You also need to be careful using C++ containers like `vector`.  You do not have explicit control of the memory used by such C++ containers, so there's no guarantee that they won't leave a copy of your sensitive data somewhere in memory.

Comment: what if i would create my own vector which would use zallocator from openssl crypto?